# mso-number-format for Accounting

Tags: html, excel

So does anyone know if there is an mso-number-format to mimic the Accounting format in Excel (Negatives are put in parens, zeros are dashes, all have 2 decimals and everything gets a dollar sign waaaay to the left)

I have an html table that i am opening in excel that i would Love to have this format.

I found the following one online, but it doens't seem to work:

mso-number-format:\#\,\#\#0\.00_\)\;\[Black\]\\(\#\,\#\#0\.00\\)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the string that I return from C# that gives a true Accounting format in Excel:

```
"\"_-$* #,##0.00_-;-$* #,##0.00_-;_-$* \\\" - \\\"??_-;_-@_-\""
```

Some important things to note when dealing with mso-number-format:

- All custom formats must be surrounded
  in double quotes
- Any double quotes
  'inside' the custom format must be
  replaced by literal "escaped double
  quotes", for Excel to interpret
  later.

So, you want the actual markup to be outputted like this

```
"_-$* #,##0.00_-;-$* #,##0.00_-;_-$* \" - \"??_-;_-@_-"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That is very close, but not quite it.  The negative number isn't in parens, instead, there is a negative symbol in front of the dollar sign.

Comment: By taking your string and tweaking it a little, I have been able to come up with the proper format.  (mso-number-format:"_-$* #,##0.00_-;$* (#,##0.00_-);_-$* \" - \"??_-;_-@_-")  but I will give you the answer, as you did all the heavy lifting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MSO is pretty proprietary to Microsoft, and hopefully this stuff won't be supported in the future so that UI Devs like me don't have to un-do it....fingers crossed.

My first inclination would be to dynamically build the excel spreadsheet with a tool like [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) so that you have 100% control over formatting, calculations, etc the way that Excel is looking for it.  Certainly there are variations of this software for the respective technology you have at your disposal (.net, java, etc)

Absent that solution, there are wonderful JQuery plugins [such as this](http://www.selfcontained.us/2008/04/22/format-currency-in-javascript-simplified/)  However, I'm not entirely sure this would suffice when you pull the html natively into Excel--it might not fire.

Do you have back-end technology available?  Something like a regex replacement could quickly solve the problem with no ill effects on Excel.

From Microsoft's own website, [CSS can't format numbers.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1202080.aspx)

Comment: Well, I am going to have to use this system for now (trust me, its not the most backwards thing about our environment).  Is there a site where i can get an intro on how these formattings work?